# Intellisense "Toggle Completion Mode" doesn't work with C++ in Visual Studio 2010 Professional

Tags: c++, visual-studio, intellisense

I am having problems with my "Toggle Completion Mode" under the Edit->Intellisense tab in Visual Studio 2010 Professional. The picture describes it quite well.

[image]

The completion mode works fine in C#.
Please help.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no possibility to turn on suggestion mode on C++ IntelliSense (both in VS 2010 and 2012).

[MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exbffbc2%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) (for VS 2010) says:

> Suggestion mode is available in Visual Basic and C#.

It was reported ([link](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/764172/vs-2012-rtm-intellisense-bug-in-c)) as a bug in VS 2012 RTM and the answer from Microsoft was:

> C++ Intellisense only has one completion mode, while VB and C# Intellisense has two different completion modes. Therefore, this command to toggle between completion modes is not available for C++ Intellisense.

If you're annoyed by inserting unwanted code after pushing space when you forget to press ESC you can make the member's list show up only after pressing ctrl+space (or alt+right arrow). In order to do that go to `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> General` and uncheck `Auto list members`.

Comment: For me the problem is the opposite of what you said, bikjub. I'm annoyed that it doesn't fix MORE of my typing. As soon as I start typing, I want it to pop up suggestions and highlight the first one. That way, when I type "mugly" and hit '.' it will replace it with "mUglyLongNameWithCaps." and a list of its members. This works beautifully in C#. In C++, however, it will show the list, but I have to hit Ctrl+Space for it to actually select the first entry. If I forget to hit that, then I end up with just "mugly." which isn't so useful. Having to do a key combo for this is really annoying.

Comment: I do not have that problem in VS 2010. When the list appears I can hit the dot key and the result is exactly the same as in C#. Perhaps there are some settings which can affect this behavior. However it was the default one in my VS Ultimate, so maybe you could fix that.

Comment: I have since started using Visual Assist X and it works beautifully. It even refactors C++. Imagine that!

Answer (score 2):

I know this was posted a long time ago but I figured I would offer my solution. I changed the shortcut to something that is not as annoying as ctrl + space. You can do this in Options -> Keyboard -> Edit.CompleteWord.

Hope this helps someone.