# Turning off auto-suggestions in Visual Studio 2019 without turning off IntelliSense

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense, autosuggest

I am new to Visual Studio and would like to disable the IntelliSense automatic suggestions without disabling IntelliSense entirely.  More precisely, I don't want popup hints continually covering the code I'm working on, but I'd still like to be able to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> to request suggestions at times.  I'm coding in C/C++.

I've seen information on how to do this for Visual Studio Code, but I haven't found anything similar for Visual Studio.

Or if this is just a matter of me not understanding how to properly use Visual Studio or IntelliSense, please help me understand or point me to a forum where true Microsoft devotees hang out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is to go to `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> General` and uncheck `Auto list members`.

Credit goes to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13534353) answer in "Intellisense “Toggle Completion Mode” doesn't work with C++ in Visual Studio 2010 Professional".

Answer (score 1):

> Turning off auto-suggestions in Visual Studio 2019 without turning off
>   IntelliSense

**Solution**

**Edit** Menu-->**Intellisense**-->click **Toggle Completion Mode**

[image]

**After that**, when you type, it will not cover the code you are working on automatically.

Hope it could help you.

Comment: +1 I was surprised that "Toggle Completion Mode" was grayed out for me, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13534353) answer explains that it's only available for Visual Basic and C#.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Mabby this can help you this is a article i found about this

https://www.technipages.com/visual-studio-turn-off-autocomplete

Comment: When I try the suggestions in your link (specifically Disable Auto Updating), Visual Studio stops making suggestions, but it unfortunately also hides all errors and warnings from the source view.