# How can Intellisense completion be enabled in Visual Studio for C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Intellisense suggestion works perfectly but I want the suggestion to be highlighted.
In C#, all it takes to toggle this feature is to press: Ctrl+Alt+Space

Or pressing the following button:
[image]

Is there no such option in case of C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned, you couldn't use Toggle Completion Mode in c++.

Refer to the Doc: [IntelliSense features in C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/visual-cpp-intellisense?view=vs-2019#intellisense-features-in-c)

You can use the menu items and keyboard shortcuts shown in the following image to access IntelliSense. (You couldn't use Toggle Completion Mode)

[image]

And I suggest you could refer to the thread: [Intellisense "Toggle Completion Mode" doesn't work with C++ in Visual Studio 2010 Professional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352466/intellisense-toggle-completion-mode-doesnt-work-with-c-in-visual-studio-201)

Comment: Thank you, sadly I expected the same, I don't understand why they don't add the same feature for C++, it doesn't even seem like a complicated issue so I don't understand what holds them back from implementing it.